# What does `kCGImageDestinationOptimizeColorForSharing` do?

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics

At the time of asking there is zero useful information on https://developer.apple.com/documentation/imageio/kcgimagedestinationoptimizecolorforsharing?language=objc

In the header it says:

```
/* Create an image using a colorspace, that has is compatible with older devices
 * The value should be kCFBooleanTrue or kCFBooleanFalse
 * Defaults to kCFBooleanFalse = don't do any color conversion
 */
```

but isn't completely clear what is going on.

I note that `sips` also seems to support it with the incredibly unhelpful information on the `man`page:

```
--optimizeColorForSharing
           Optimize color for sharing.
```

Any details about what is really going on would be appreciated.